# jQuery - multiple modals separate handling

Tags: javascript, jquery

If you click the Apple icon the modal appears and then if click away it disappears.

If you click the Google icon the modal appears (and is set to not disappear).

**The goal:** to `toggle` the `active` class for the Google `modal` when the `#google` icon is clicked (i.e show/hide the modal when the google img is clicked and not when the user clicks away like the apple modal)

```js
$('.button').on('click', function() {
  const id = $(this).prop('id');
  $('.modal').each(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active', $(this).data('id') == id);
  });
});
$(document).on("click", function(e) {
  if (($(".apple-modal").hasClass("active")) && (!$(".modal, .modal *, .button").is(e.target))) {
    $(".modal").removeClass("active");
  }
});
```

```css
.button {
  height: 30px;
}

.header {
  height: 15px;
  background: #eee;
}

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 72px;
  right: 15px;
  z-index: 6;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: scale(0.5);
  transform-origin: top right;
  transition: 0.15s;
  box-shadow: 0 1.5px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0 1.5px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.modal:after {
  content: "";
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  background: #eee;
  top: -6px;
  right: 8px;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: rotate(45deg) scale(0.5);
  transition: 0.15s;
}

.modal.active {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.modal.active:after {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://www.dignitasteam.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/3050613-inline-i-2-googles-new-logo-copy.png" class="button test" id="google" />
<img src="https://www.arabianbusiness.com/sites/default/files/styles/full_img/public/images/2017/01/17/apple-logo-rainbow.jpg" class="test button" id="apple" />
<div class="modal" data-id="google">
  <div class="header">Google</div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      First</li>
    <li>
      Second</li>
    <li>
      Third</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="modal apple-modal" data-id="apple">
  <div class="header">Apple</div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      First</li>
    <li>
      Second</li>
    <li>
      Third</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you  looking for the JQuery 'toggleClass()' function? https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a click event listener for Elements with the `data-close` attribute to remove the active class from the selector given to the `data-close` attribute when the Element is clicked on and the element the selector gets is visible and has a class of active.

```js
$('[data-close]').click(function(e){
  const dataClose = $(this).attr('data-close');
  const elem = $('[data-id="'+dataClose+'"]').length?$('[data-id="'+dataClose+'"]'):$(dataClose);
  if(elem.hasClass("active")&&elem.is(":visible")){
    elem.removeClass("active");
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  }
});
$('.button').on('click', function() {
  const id = $(this).prop('id');
  $('.modal').each(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active', $(this).data('id') == id);
  });
});
$(document).on("click", function(e) {
  if (($(".apple-modal").hasClass("active")) && (!$(".modal, .modal *, .button").is(e.target))) {
    $(".modal").removeClass("active");
  }
});
```

```css
.button {
  height: 30px;
}

.header {
  height: 15px;
  background: #eee;
}

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 72px;
  right: 15px;
  z-index: 6;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: scale(0.5);
  transform-origin: top right;
  transition: 0.15s;
  box-shadow: 0 1.5px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0 1.5px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.modal:after {
  content: "";
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  background: #eee;
  top: -6px;
  right: 8px;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: rotate(45deg) scale(0.5);
  transition: 0.15s;
}

.modal.active {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.modal.active:after {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://www.dignitasteam.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/3050613-inline-i-2-googles-new-logo-copy.png" class="button test" id="google" data-close="google"/>
<img src="https://www.arabianbusiness.com/sites/default/files/styles/full_img/public/images/2017/01/17/apple-logo-rainbow.jpg" class="test button" id="apple" />
<div class="modal" data-id="google">
  <div class="header">Google</div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      First</li>
    <li>
      Second</li>
    <li>
      Third</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="modal apple-modal" data-id="apple">
  <div class="header">Apple</div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      First</li>
    <li>
      Second</li>
    <li>
      Third</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```